# How to invoke method with sql request in separate class from Groovy script in SOAP UI?

Tags: testing, groovy, soapui

Friends, hello. 
I'am trying to use elements of object oriented approach in SOAP UI groovy scripting.
I read manual about "How to write a reusable script" here http://forum.loadui.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15744
and I am trying to write a separate class with method which get data from database and set up address properties (Address).
My problem is that i receive the  error message

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sql1 for class
>   Utils error at line: 138

when run "main" Groovy script.

"Main" Groovy Script looks like:

```
// get a reference to the library TestSuite
library = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["Library"]
// find the module within the library 
module = library.testCases["module-name"].testSteps["Utils"]
// initialise the library; which places an instance of Example in the context
module.run(testRunner, context)
// get the instance of example from the context.
def utils = context.utils
// run the method, with parameter
log.info "utils.setAddress() = " + utils.setAddress("LivingPlace");
```

setAddress method is determined in class Utils which is looked like:

```
    import groovy.sql.Sql;
    class Utils
    {
       def log
       def context
       def testRunner
       // Class constructor with same case as Class name
       def Utils(logIn, contextIn, testRunnerIn)
       {
         this.log = logIn
          this.context = contextIn
          this.testRunner = testRunnerIn
       }

    def  setAddress (addressType)
    {
         log.info testRunner;
         log.info context;
         log.info "Call the DB" ;

com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
sql1 = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://SRV1:1433; databaseName=DB;", "user", "123", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");


sql1.eachRow('select top 1 '+     
                  'Country '+    
       'from Address') 
    { row ->
        testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Address'].setPropertyValue("'country",  "$row.Country");

     }
      return addressType //just for test
    }
    }


context.setProperty ("utils", new Utils(log, context, testRunner) )
        log.info "Library Context:"+context;
```

If i delete everything related with sql it works fine. How to invoke the setAddress method without error described earlier and set Adress properties?

Comment: Should that be `def sql1 = ...`?

Comment: SiKing, yes! you are absolutly right. Thank you very much. It works. But i can't understand why it worked in "main" class without def. I'm new in Groovy.